# How can I create an activity indicator in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, artwork

I tried looking for the images to create an spinner like the ones found in other Ubuntu Touch apps.

I found this image, but it isn't spinning:

[image]

Source: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/trunk/view/head:/themes/Ambiance/qmltheme/artwork/spinner%408.png

**How do I create an activity indicator and make it spin like other apps do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an activity indicator in Ubuntu Touch, you can use code similar to the following:

```
ActivityIndicator {
    running: // ... Code to decide when to show the spinner ...
    visible: running
}
```

This will create an activity indicator and show it and make it spin based on the code assigned to the `running` property.

Here is what the activity indicator will look like when it's running:

[image: Activity Indicator]